# Google Chrome: keyboard shortcut to view Resources / Inspect Element?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome has a  Firebug-like feature where you click on a page element and choose "Inspect Element".

I am always jumping into the Resources view to look at HTTP requests.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open this tool?

Comment: Official docs & more useful shortcuts: [Chrome Developer Tools: Keyboard Shortcuts](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/shortcuts.html)

Comment: Here are useful informations; http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

Comment: Also, F12 brings up the Inspect Element pane in Chrome on Ubuntu

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just discovered that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> works. Just like Firebug.

On OS X, that's <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks horizens - just what I was looking for. Agreed, the Inspector has gotten so good I no longer have a need for Firebug. Buh-bye, FF.

Comment: Changed my answer... having the same shortcut as Firefox is great.

Comment: Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + C is pretty useful too, since it allows you to select a specific element to inspect without navigating through the context menu. See also https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts

Comment: does anyone know how to change this keyboard shortcut? In Firebug, you can configure the shortcut. It Chrome, it seems to be hard-set. for a reason why, I use the dvorak keyboard layout and the C key is far away from my left hand.

Answer (score 18):

actually holding N and right-clicking somewhere on the page opens the inspect window and takes you to the piece of code where you clicked on in tnnnnnnnnhe page. i just found this out.

Comment: Your typo is unintentionally hilarious :)

Comment: +1 for a specific point on the page (even if the OP only wanted the general window). This is nice for hover issues, leaving the mouse right where it is, without having to move the mouse down the popup menu.

Comment: @goodeye note: you also simulate hover by clicking the toggle element state (dotted-box-with-arrow) icon, it's on the right of the 'styles' accordian-menu if you can't find it google images for "toggle element state"

Comment: My god, all this time I've been right clicking and doing "Inspect Element" wasting all that time.

Comment: @Myster, Nice tip, Btw  does the [toggle device mode](https://www.google.com/search?q=toggle+device+mode&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=NdZaVeS5NYOXuQTSmoHACw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1093&bih=542) only do resizing?

Comment: I was searching for this. Superconvenietnt. In Firefox it is Q and it is an even better shortcut for this.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> opens the developer tools, to the last section you were in. If you were last in the Resources section then you will see the Resources.

I don't think there is a keyboard short cut specifically for *Inspect Element*, as this depends on context (ie. the location of the mouse)?

Comment: Frankadelic really wants to open the Developer Tools to access the Resources panel, not the Elements panel, so Ctrl+Shift+I is a good shortcut to use: it opens the Developer Tools the same way you left them. (Chrome's context menus have very few options, so *right-click, Inspect element* is common way people suggest getting to any of the Developer Tools via mouse.)

Comment: Bavi_H, that's correct.